# Missing Azure USGov Sharepoint Online API Access option in App Registration

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-gov

When creating a new application registration in Azure USGov I do not have SharePoint Online as an option under required permissions.  Only AAD, Graph, WASM, and O365 Management API's.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

do you see "Office 365 SharePoint Online" as an option? Below is what I see as options.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bernie.  The only options I have are Windows Azure Active Directory, Microsoft Graph, Windows Azure Service Management API and Office 365 Management APIs.

Comment: I see the same in a different tenant that doesn't have Office 365 in it. I'm thinking those APIs don't show up until Office 365 has been provisioned into the tenant. What scenario are you trying to address? A security principal from a tenant without Office in it wouldn't have access to authenticate to SharePoint Online for instance, unless maybe it's a B2B scenario.